# Action of a HTMLFormElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, forms

Here is an HTML snippet to reproduce the problem:

```
<form id=foo action='https://[::1]/'>
    <input type=hidden name=action value=xyz>
</form>

<script>
    window.alert(document.getElementById('foo').action);
</script>
```

At first I was using jQuery `.prop()` so I thought that was the problem but it happens in pure JavaScript as well.

I'm expecting the result to be `https://[::1]/` but for some reason it gives me `[HTMLInputElement]`. According to MDN, the `action` property of [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) should be a DOMString reflecting the HTML `action` attribute, not an HTMLElement.

This behaviour is present in both Internet Explorer and Chrome so I don't think it's a bug with the browser's implementation. The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-fs-action) states:

> The `action` IDL attribute must reflect the content attribute of the same name, except that on getting, when the content attribute is missing or its value is the empty string, the document's address must be returned instead.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) says:

```
getter (RadioNodeList or Element) (DOMString name);
```

This means a form has properties referencing each input element by name: `<input name="user">` will automatically define `form.user`. In your case, `<input name="action">` causes `form.action` to be overridden, referencing that element instead of the form action attribute.

Just retrieve the attribute directly:

```
form.getAttribute("action");
```

Or rename your input:

```
<input name="control-action">
```

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 To make it easier to access form elements. We didn't have methods like `querySelector` yet when they wrote this spec...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

```
alert(document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('action'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbgp7gne/

In your example it happens because you have a child element in your form with the attribute `name` of 'action'. The JS is returning a HTMLCollection for your form and `.action` is a child node of that. Forms are special.

Rename it to see your original JS working as expected:

```
<form id=foo action='https://[::1]/'>
    <input type=hidden name=definitelyNOTaction value=xyz>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbgp7gne/1/

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to my question…

Comment: Then clarify your question. The only one in your post is 'Am I missing something here?' I thought that was rhetorical but to answer it... Yes.

Comment: My question is why does that happen